# call property to populate in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

Hey all new to the MVC world so I'm sure I am not doing something correct here. I am trying to call a function from the model page from my view index page to populate some tooltips.

In my model:

```
public class tips
{
    public List<string> allTips()
    {
        List<string> theTips = new List<string>();

        theTips.Add("example 1");
        theTips.Add("example 2");

        return theTips;
    }

    private List<string> _tips;
    public List<string> getTips { get { return _tips; } set { _tips = allTips(); } }
}
```

And in my view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var blah = new tips().getTips;

    ViewBag.pageTips = blah;

    return getMainData();
}
```

And then I have this on the razor page:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.pageTips[1])
```

Which should display **example 2** on the page but instead it just displays *null* as the value for the toolTips.

Currently it has a value of *null* when it gets to the return for the pageTips in my view.

So what would I be doing incorrectly? I put some stops here and there and notice that it never calls the **allTips()** function so that's a good starting place as to what I need to do in order to do that.

I just figured that calling the **.getTips** would fire off the **theTips** function?

Comment: Are you sure that the getMainData method does not do something that clean the Viewbag?

Comment: @RobertoCarlos yeah, it just places some more data into ViewBags and such but nothing in the pageTips ViewBag.

Comment: Your model is *very* strange.  But ultimately you're never instantiating `_tips`.  Which is why it's `null`.

Comment: @David That's what I need help with - the correct way to get it to call _tips. Though whats so strange about it? I am just putting toolTip sentences in one place that I can pull out for each of my controls on the view page. Just wanted a single place to store them instead of in javascript.

Comment: @StealthRT: What's strange is that you have a method which acts like a constructor (sort of), you only call that method in a setter which doesn't act like a setter, and then since you never call that setter your field is never initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the concept of `setter` and using it as an "initializer", a setter is meant to set the value, to change it in other word. if you want to initialize it do it in the constructor.

Here you are using two different Lists, I don't really know why.
A working code would be:

```
public class tips
{
    public tips()
    {
        _tips = new List<string>();

        _tips.Add("example 1");
        _tips.Add("example 2");
    }

    private List<string> _tips;
    public List<string> getTips { get { return _tips; } set { _tips = value; } }
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
ViewBag.pageTips = new tips().getTips;
```

Then call it this way in the view:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.pageTips[1])
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Clearly explaining the misconception about completely ignoring the value passed to the setter is a **very** important concept to grasp. Anyone else using that class would be completely flabbergasted that the values they assigned to a property are nowhere to be found.

Comment: @krillgar indeed not using `value` in the property's setter is clearly an anti-pattern

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Piou! Indeed this is the correct answer since it mirrors my own example above - but solves the issue I was having.

Comment: I sticked as much as possible to your code, as a personal note, I would not name `getTips` a property but just `Tips` as mentioned in others very legit answers.

Comment: also class name in C# should start with Capital letters

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confusing *constructors* with *properties* in your model, which is very strange.  I suspect you want something like this instead:

```
public class TipsObj
{
    // a property
    public List<string> Tips { get; set; }

    // a constructor
    public TipsObj()
    {
        Tips = new List<string>();

        Tips.Add("example 1");
        Tips.Add("example 2");
    }
}
```

The idea here is that the constructor is called *by default* when you create a new instance of the object, so your `Tips` property will automatically be populated right away just by creating an instance of this.

Then in your controller action you can simply do this:

```
var tips = new TipsObj();

ViewBag.pageTips = tips.Tips;
```

Which will create an instance of the `TipsObj` and set a `ViewBag` property to the `Tips` property of that instance.  Which was initialized in the constructor of that object.

Note that none of this really has anything to do with MVC, this is just creating an object in C# and using a property on that object.

Note also that I changed some of the names here.  In C# class names should begin with a capital letter.  Also, you don't want to call *everything* "tips" (and you don't want to call *anything* "blah").  Using meaningful and intuitive names makes your code easier to understand, which will help you understand what you're writing.

Comment: Thanks for all the knowledge, David. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Change your model like the following:

```
public class Tips
{
    private List<string> _tips {get; set;}

    public Tips()
    {
        _tips = new List<string>();
        _tips.Add("example 1");
        _tips.Add("example 2");
    }

    public List<string> getTips() 
    { 
        return _tips;
    }
}
```

Then use it :

```
ViewBag.pageTips = new Tips().getTips();
```

Comment: **Method must have a return type** error on public Tips() function.

Comment: @StealthRT: The code in this answer doesn't produce that error.  (Note also that C# is case-sensitive.)

Comment: @StealthRT it is a constructor, should be same name as your class

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the help, meda!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here, but I'll start with answering your question directly... the reason ViewBag.pageTips[1] is null is because you never initialize the _tips array in your model.  The only code that would do that is in the getTips property's setter, which is never invoked.  If you attach a debugger it'll be apparent :)

You could refactor this in a few ways, including changing the allTips() method to a constructor, and initializing your collection there.

I don't want to put an example of that directly though.  You mentioned you were new to MVC, so I want to show you how this should really be done.  One of the big benefits of MVC is Model Binding, so forget about ViewBag. 
Try this instead:

**The Model**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class TipsModel
    {
        public List<string> Tips { get; }

        public TipsModel()
        {
            Tips = new List<string> {"example 1", "example 2"};
        }
    }
}
```

**The Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new TipsModel();

        return View(model);
    }
```

**The View**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.TipsModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Model.Tips[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! However, as you probably see in my example, I already have a View return **return getMainData()** so how would I return both **getMainData()** and **View(model)**?

Comment: I wouldn't have getMainData() at all.  Where it's invoked in your code doesn't seem to make sense.  The name infers that you are "getting data", but since it's being called as part of the return statement of an action, the getMainData() method must have a return type of some kind of ActionResult (which isn't data).  Let the model get the data for you, and pass it to the View.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Honestly @Steve it does not. Simply trying to understand the MVC is much of an issue for me. I'm from the ASP.net forms past and so I am just used to getting the data for any given page in the code behind without having it in a different location that I have to reference and all. Just seems like more work than its worth just to have code in another place.

Comment: MVC is definitely a different philosophy than WebForms.  The idea is that you are separating concerns between presentation and business logic. I'm no evangelist for MVC, but since you're trying out MVC... try not apply your WebForms practices to your MVC projects.  It will drive other developers mad ;)  May I suggest this video to help you (https://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight)... it will explain the rationale for MVC far better than I could.